# How to use an rng value as value for time.sleep

Tags: python

I'm trying to make a simple timer that after the time restarts the whole body of code but list can't be used as value, is there any other alternative?

```
randomlist = random.sample(range(200, 330),1)
time.sleep(x)
```

Comment: what about random.randint?

Comment: It's not clear what you're doing - can you add some more of your code? A `while loop` is useful for repeating something (like running a body of code)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you mean to so something like this:

```
from time import sleep
from random import uniform

# sleep something between 2 and 5 seconds
sleep(uniform(2, 5))
```

[`time.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) accepts a single `float` as number of seconds to sleep; [`random.uniform`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/random.html#random.uniform) provides just that.